Is there a method to retrieve integers $ n,m $ from the value of $a=m+n\sqrt{3}$
Given the value of the expression $a=m+n\sqrt{3}$, where m and n are integers, is there a way to retrieve the values of m and n? If also $a=m'+n'\sqrt{3}$, then $m-m' = (n-n')\sqrt{3}$. The left and right side can only be both rational if $n=n'$ and thus $m=m'$, so $m$ and $n$ are unique.
Being a root of a quadratic equation, $a$ displays a periodic pattern in its continued fractions representation, but it didn't bring me any further.
If the value of $a$ is given in finite decimal form, in fact we define an interval around the value, say $a-\varepsilon <m+n\sqrt{3} < a+ \varepsilon$. This leads to infinitely many solutions, unless we specify limits for $n$ and $m$ or recognize already a periodic pattern in the continued fractions terms. Therefore assume $a$ is defined in a continued fractions form with a periodic tail. This is an exact representation of $a$.

@Sahaj $m,n$ are integers so it is real, and irrational if $n \neq 0$.

I'd calculate the continued fraction representation of $a$, until it repeats. Then use that to recover the square root expression by constructing the quadratic that has (part of) that continued fraction expression as a root.

This might sound silly, but it's a serious question: what do you know about $a$, besides it being of the form $m+n\sqrt{3}$? I don't know how much you can glean with a finite decimal expansion, since for $\alpha\in [0,1)$ and $\epsilon >0$, there are infinitely many $n$ with $|{n \sqrt{3}} - \alpha|<\epsilon$. So even if you have arbitrary precision, if $m$ is negative then you can't determine $m,n$, though maybe you could if you require $|m|,|n|\le N$. My understanding is that there is no known pattern in the decimal (or other base) representation, but I can't find a reference.

@Integrand FWIW, I also consider your question to be serious, as I have a similar concern myself.

On the other hand, if you know the minimal polynomial of this quadratic integer, the answer is straightforward.

If you have the continued fraction representation, then it is quite easy to recover the surd form. Here is an example.
Suppose $a=1.5358983848622454129451073169883...$.
The continued fraction representation can be found by noting down the integer part, then taking the reciprocal of the fractional part, and repeating the same steps on the resulting number. With the above you get:
$[1; 1, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2, 6...]$.
I am of course assuming that you have enough decimal digits of accuracy to calculate the continued fraction far enough to recognise the repeating tail. If you are not sure you have enough, simply increment the last decimal digit you have of $a$ and calculate its continued fraction again. When the numbers start to differ from your original continued fraction, you have reached the end of the information you can extract.
Let $x$ be repeating tail section:
$$x = 6 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{6 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{...}}}}$$
Clearly you can substitute $x$ for the tail to get:
$$x = 6 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{x}}$$
This can be simplified and solved:
$$x = 6 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{x}} = 6 + \frac{1}{\frac{2x+1}{x}} = 6 + \frac{x}{2x+1} = \frac{6(2x+1)+x}{2x+1} = \frac{13x+6}{2x+1} $$
$$x(2x+1)=13x+6 \\
x^2-6x-3=0\\
x=3\pm 2\sqrt{3}$$
Only the positive root is relevant here. Now we know the value of the tail of the continued fraction, we have to tackle the head:
$$ a = 1 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}
= 1 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+1}{x}}}
= 1 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{x+1}}
= 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{2x+1}{x+1}} 
= 1 + \frac{x+1}{2x+1} 
= \frac{3x+2}{2x+1} $$
Substituting $x=3+ 2\sqrt{3}$ gives us our value for $a$:
$$ a = \frac{11+6\sqrt{3}}{7+4\sqrt{3}}
= \frac{11+6\sqrt{3}}{7+4\sqrt{3}} \times \frac{7-4\sqrt{3}}{7-4\sqrt{3}}
= \frac{(11+6\sqrt{3})(7-4\sqrt{3})}{49-48} \\
=  77-72 + 42\sqrt{3}-44\sqrt{3}
=  5-2\sqrt{3}$$

+1; it might be worth mentioning how many decimals are needed to see the repetition of the continued fraction (ex: do you need 30 decimals, or will 12 suffice?).

Is there any guarantee on the length of the period (which would make it easier to recognize)?  For example the example given here repeats with period 2; so does $\sqrt{3}$ itself; but $5 \sqrt{3} = [8; 1, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 1, 16, \ldots]$ with period 4 and $6 \sqrt{3} = [10; 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 20, \ldots]$ with period 8.  It appears that the period depends only on $|n|$.

@MichaelLugo That is a good question, and I don't actually know the answer to it. BTW, $m$ only affects the first term of the continued fraction, and obviously has no effect on the period.

@Michael Lugo  And  within de periodic patterns there are often also palindromes.

$m$ only affects the first term, but it's not obvious that the sign of $n$ doesn't matter.  (I haven't tried that hard to prove it.)

One approach is to run a lattice reduction algorithm on the integer lattice generated by
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
v_0=(1 & 0 & 0 & \lfloor N \rceil) \\
v_1=(0 & 1 & 0 & \lfloor Na \rceil) \\ 
v_2=(0 & 0 & 1 & \lfloor Na^2 \rceil) \\
\end{array}
$$
given approximations for $Na$ and $Na^2$,
and where $N$ is some "large" number.  When this finds a short(est) vector $(k_0 \; k_1 \; k_2 \; k_3)$ then $k_0v_0 + k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 \approx 0$ means that you may have found a minimal polynomial for $a$, i.e. $k_0 + k_1a + k_2a^2 = 0$.
Once you have a minimal polynomial, it is easy to find $m$ and $n$.
Notice that the result is not unique as it depends on how good the approximation for $a$ is, and how $N$ is chosen.
For lattice reduction, see for example Wikipedia:LLL lattice basis reduction algorithm and Wikipedia: Integer relation algorithm.

So here is an example in Sage.  I am not at all familiar with Sage, so please bear with me...
#!/usr/bin/env sage

N = 1000000000

a = 1.5358983848622454129451073169883

Na = Integer((N*a).round())
Naa = Integer((N*a*a).round())

show (Na)
show (Naa)

M = Matrix (ZZ,
            [ [1, 0, 0, N],
              [0, 1, 0, Na],
              [0, 0, 1, Naa] ])

show ("matrix:")
show (M)
show ("reduced:")
show (M.LLL())

The value of $a=1.5358983...$ is like from the other answer, but notice that due to the choice of $N=10^9$ only 9 fractional digits of $a$ are used.  Running the script prints:
1535898385
2358983849
'matrix:'
[         1          0          0 1000000000]
[         0          1          0 1535898385]
[         0          0          1 2358983849]
'reduced:'
[    13    -10      1     -1]
[ -3815  -3437   3855 -11350]
[ -6847  -8462   8412   3918]

Where the 1st vector $(13, -10, 1, \cdots)$ of the reduced basis is short, and hence
$$
p(a)=13-10a+a^2 \approx 0
$$
So one possible candidate for a polynomial is $p(x)$, and indeed the zeros of $p$ are
$$
5\pm2\sqrt 3
$$
with
$$
5-2\sqrt 3 \approx 1.53589838\ldots\approx a
$$
Notice that we did not use that $a$ is of the form $n+m\sqrt{3}$.  All we used was that $a$ is of degree 2.
As for the value of $N$, I used the script below to print the results for various values of $N$:
'reduced wih N = 10 : ' (-1, -1, 1, -1)
'reduced wih N = 100 : ' (4, 2, -3, 0)
'reduced wih N = 1000 : ' (-4, -2, 3, 5)
'reduced wih N = 10000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 0)
'reduced wih N = 100000 : ' (13, -10, 1, -2)
'reduced wih N = 1000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 4)
'reduced wih N = 10000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, -2)
'reduced wih N = 100000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 5)
'reduced wih N = 1000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, -1)
'reduced wih N = 10000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, -4)
'reduced wih N = 100000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 2)
'reduced wih N = 1000000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 2)
'reduced wih N = 10000000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 5)
'reduced wih N = 100000000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, -5)
'reduced wih N = 1000000000000000 : ' (13, -10, 1, 4)

So $N$ must not be too small. Notice that the floating-point values are IEEE double, which has a machine epsilon of around $10^{-16}$, hence the Sage script only goes up to $N=10^{15}$:
a = 1.5358983848622454129451073169883

def print_poly_for (a, N):
    Na = Integer((N*a).round())
    Naa = Integer((N*a*a).round())

    M = Matrix (ZZ,
                [ [1, 0, 0, N],
                  [0, 1, 0, Na],
                  [0, 0, 1, Naa] ])

    show ("reduced wih N = %s : " % N, M.LLL()[0])

for n in range(1, 16):
    print_poly_for (a, 10 ** n)


I assume here that $m,n \ge 0$. When they have different signs, things are probably harder.
If you are given the decimal expansion of $a=m+n\sqrt{3}$ with $d$ correct (not rounded) digits after the decimal point, then you can bound $n \ge 0$, according to the table below:
$$
\begin{array}{rc}
d & N \\
1 & 7 \\
2 & 59 \\
3 & 788 \\
4 & 2972 \\
5 & 40554 \\
6 & 564720 \\
7 & 7865526 \\
\end{array}
$$
This means that the first $d$ digits of the fractional part of $a$ determine $n \ge 0$ if $n < N$.
Once you have $n$, you can get $m$, by using a good approximation of $\sqrt3$.
